# pre footer fixed at bottom that sits on footer

Tags: css, css-position

I  have kinda 2 footers. 
A normal grey footer and a blue footer that is fixed at the bottom of window.

I want that when the user scrolls down the blue footer sit on top of the grey footer instead of remaining at bottom of the window.

Here is an example of what i got:

http://jsfiddle.net/fV3Tz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to resort to js to achieve this. I would love to hear if there actualy is a pure css solution, but i doubt it.  I updated your fiddle with a small js example: http://jsfiddle.net/fV3Tz/1/

As you can see all i did was add a few lines of jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  // when scrolled
    footTop = $('#footer').offset().top;  // check top off footer
    windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()  // check bottom of viewport
    if (footTop <= windowBottom) { // if top of footer in view
       $("#footer-azul").css('bottom', windowBottom - footTop); // move the azul up with the amount of footer that is in view
    } else {  // if top of footer not in view
          $("#footer-azul").css('bottom', 0);    // move the azul all the way down        
    }             
});​
```

Comment: i thought that javascript was going to rescue me. Thanks!